# Feral cats and stray cats

Tags: cats, feral

I had one feral cat I fed who turned out to be pregnant. She had babies, then a year later the babies had babies. All of them grew up under my house and have been fed by me. They have never been inside and don't let me touch them but a few rub against my leg.

I finally found somebody to trap and fix them. I will get that done. They trap neuter and return.

I'm in a rental house and may have to move. I'm in a semi rural tiny town with no traffic light surrounded by farms.

I contacted the SPCA and was told they don't take ferals as there are too many. I called the county and i was told they will all be euthanized. It tears me up to think about them being euthanized!

Seems I made a mistake feeding the one but who knew she was pregnant. Now I've got 10 or 12 who love it here as I give them dry and wet food. They have a stream to drink water from and they stay under the house for shelter.

What a mess... If I move it is highly likely I won't be able to take them. I tried to do what I thought was right and now its an issue. I'm shocked to learn no organization will try to find them homes. All I keep hearing is strays/ferals are a huge problem here. So frustrating and heartbreaking.

I luv animals and don't know what to do!

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see how this site works, it only takes a minute. This is no discussion forum, but a Q&A site, where every post must state one clear question for us to answer or one problem you seek a solution for. "I have 12 stray cats, what should I do?" is too broad to give you any meaningful answer. Please click on [edit] to edit your post.

Comment: Yes, there are too many ferals to find homes for all of them. Trap/neuter/release is the best solution that has been found short of euthanasia, but that takes some dedication (and some money) to keep up with. Humane euthanasia is not a great option but not the worst possible outcome.

Comment: It is a known problem for new users, that one "new line" command (or "enter" button) alone will not result in a new line. Instead you need two of them and will get a free line and a new paragraph. So have a look into the unformatted text can be helpful to see if the post really lacks formatting and experienced users can edit and help for the first question.

Answer (score 3):

There really aren't any good solutions.

There are already too many non-feral cats to find homes for them all. And ferals don't always adapt well to being pets, even when they aren't afraid of humans.

In some places there are organizations that will try to transport ferals to farms as "barn cats" as part of a trap/neuter/release program.   Otherwise, the best you can do may indeed be to get them neutered and release them back into your own neighborhood. They will at least help discourage more ferals from moving in, and limit the number of kittens for the next decade or so.

I'm afraid you are going to have to accept that they will have to find their own food. They will spread out in search of prey if there isn't enough locally (and there probably isn't), so they will probably be ok in that regard. They won't be as happy or as healthy as pets, but they will be healthier than they would have been if you hadn't been feeding them.

Feral cats really are wild animals, even if they are acclimated to humans. You have done what you could for them. You are going to have to let go and trust them to look after themselves.

(Re "who knew": An un-neutered animal *will* reproduce. That's how life works. Hence the need for trap/neuter/release programs.)